# I can't figure out how to place the words for each div element in the middle of each side using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

Just like the title says, I'm trying to create a rough layout for a website and I want to not only center the words on each side like they already are, but also have them in the middle. When I use transform and put the words in the middle of the page, the h1 element doesn't move but then the p element keeps going down the page rather than adjusting it with every new row. Any tips?

```
    <div class="left-side" >
        <h1>Welcome.</h1>
            <p>I want to welcome you!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side">
        <h1>Corey Michaud.</h1>
            <p>Corey is my name :)</p>
    </div>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

.left-side {
    background: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
}

.right-side {
    background: black;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 72px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

p {
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You want to center both `h1` and `p` vertically and horizontally within their parent, Right ?

Comment: Yes! The horizontal center was easy but vertical-align: middle or center are not working :(

Comment: Add `display:flex;align-items:center;flex-direction:column;justify-content: center;` to those `<div>`s

Comment: YOOO thank you it worked! I'm new to html and css and I understand how align-items work, but how do the flex elements work? If you don't mind doing a real quick explanation :)

Comment: `align-items` property align the flex items according to the flex axis which you can control using `flex-direction`. However `justify-content` aligns items in the opposite axis. When it comes to CSS grid  `justify-content` is for the `Y` axis *(vertically)* and `align-items` is for `X` axis *(horizontally)*

Comment: Oh okay thank you! Is flexbox more useful than grids? I hear people prefer one over the other

Comment: Neither is better than the other, and neither came to replace the other, it's just different tools you use them when you need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use css flexbox. Add

```css
.left-side, .right-side{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

Hopefully this is helpful!

Comment: Don't forget `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: Yes, thanks! It works without, but it is a definitely better coding habit to include it.

Comment: It's works without it, but the point is to keep the layout as the op wants it.